# Measure/plot/value of autocorrelation changing over time

Tags: time-series, arima, vector-autoregression

How do I get a measure of changes in autocorrelation over time ? As far as I can gather Arima models uses all its measuring points to develop the model and presupposes stability to be done. Should I just do sussesive arima models with i.e. 30 days intervals and compare, or could someone come up with a clever/or simple solution so I can generate a (probably linear ) graph of the changes in the auto correlation over time. Ill be measuring mood over time in psychotherapy, an a positive find would be that mood gets less sticky over time. (The question pertains to both an Univariate analysis (ARMA)) and a multivariate analysis (VAR-modelling)...any answers to one or the other are very welcome. I'm pretty new to statistics, so it might be a surprisingly simple answer to this one? or maybe not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably like you suggest, break the data into chunks, compute the autocorrelation for each chunk and see if they appear to be changing.

You could expand a little on this by using a moving window instead of just discrete chunks (i.e. compute on observations 1-30, then 2-31, then 3-32, ...).

If you want to get more fancy then one approach to fitting an AR model is to fit a multivariate normal to all the data where the covariance matrix is a specific structure where observations different by 1 time period have correlation $\rho$, those different by 2 time periods have correlation $\rho^2$, those different by 3 have correlation $\rho^3$, etc.  So to fit your model, you could add a term that also takes time into account so that the correlation can change over time as well, then fit that model and see if the extra term really does show a deterioration (or increase, or stability).  I would suggest using something like Stan (http://mc-stan.org/) to fit this more complicated model.